# Is it possible to link images to different URLs?

Tags: views, media

Using View's module it is possible to create a page to display some content horizontally. I have done this using carousel feature.
The content type that these contents belong to have an `image_field` and a `body_field`.

What I want from Drupal 8 is that when these images are clicked they should redirect visitors to a specific page (not to the node's / content's page).

Is it possible to do so or using html on `body_field` to place the images with `a` and `img` tags is the only way?

UPDATE:

At first I understood nothing from the answer below but a day later it just made sense like in the movie "Phenomenon"; I was struck by a mysterious light in the sky. Here is what I did:

- Created a new `link_field` inside the content type that I am using on this **View**.
- Went back to the content / node (under **Content**) where I wanted to add the link to the image and filled the `link_field`
- Added this newly created `link_field` to the **View** and made it hidden by checking the box titled *"Exclude from display"*.
- Clicked on the `image_field` on **View** settings (under the FEILDS) and *REWRITE RESULTS* > check the box *"Output this field as a custom link"* (An empty area shows up to be filled here).
- Went down and expanded the drop down list titled *"REPLACEMENT PATTERNS"* and found the `link_field`'s name (The name you gave to your `link field` you have created it) and copied the string (something like `{{ the_name_of_my_link_field }}`).
- Pasted this string into the empty area above then Saved, Saved, Saved to exit.

That's all!

Answer (score 2):

You can do this using the Rewrite feature of Views.

These instructions assume that the view is set to show **Fields** (instead of **Content** or something else).  If you are not using fields, you can switch to fields under **FORMAT** in the Views UI.

1. Click the image field in your view and select the checkbox **Exclude from display**.
2. Add a new field to the view of type **Custom text**.
3. On the custom text configuration screen, check the *Replacement patterns*. This will include some twig tokens that you can use, including the image file. You can then use this token to add HTML to the **Text** field to get the link you want.  For example, `<a href="/mypage">{{ image }}</a>`.

Note that when using Views twig replacement tokens in a custom text field, order matters!  If your custom text field is above another field, it won't be able to get the tokens from the field(s) below.  In that case, you will need to click the flippy triangle to the right of **Fields** in the Views UI and choose rearrange, and then move the field that uses tokens below the field(s) that supply the tokens.

Another option is to open up the settings for your image field in Views and, under **Rewrite results**, click **Output this field as a custom link** and set the link options there.

Comment: Thanks, it took me a while to understand it.